# No "http://" or "www" in front of URL when visiting newly purchase domain from GoDaddy

Tags: url, http, no-www

I just purchase a domain name from GoDaddy and when going to the website it is only `example.com` and not `www.example.com` or `http://example.com`.

Why is this? I have not been able to find any examples of this while doing some searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http is a [protocol](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), it's always present on a full URI. It can be replaced by other protocols such as FTP or HTTPS.

the www. is a subdomain. This is part of a [fully qualified domain name.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)

If you're looking to implement a subdomain, then your server needs to reply to the request and you need to [set it as valid in your DNS.](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/edit-a-subdomain-19940)

Comment: "http is a protocol, it's always present on a full URI" -- Except that most browsers now hide it in the URL bar.